# Como limpar um erro do ModelState com propriedade específica?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Criei projeto asp.net mvc core 2.2 com conta individual.

Segue código:

```
[BindProperty]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }

public class InputModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo \"Cartão\" é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Cartão:")]
    public string Card { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Cards { get; set; }
}

if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Input.Card"))
    ModelState["Input.Card"].Errors.Clear();
```

Com esse código acima não funciona, já o código a seguir funciona:

```
ModelState.Clear(); // Limpa todos
```

Já tentei dessa maneira e não funciona:

```
foreach (var modelValue in ModelState.Values)
{
    modelValue.Errors.Clear();
}
```

Continua o mesmo erro no `ModelState`.

Não estou conseguindo limpar um erro da propriedade específica, alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução:

```
if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Input.Card"))
    ModelState.Remove("Input.Card");
```